# Instantiating c++ interface as a child class

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface

I have an interface, let's call it `Creature`, who has virtual functions that cause it to be abstract.

I have child classes of this interface such as `Dog`, `Cat`, and `Pig`.

The compiler doesn't seem to like the following line due to not being able to declare variable `thing` to be of abstract type `Creature`.

```
Creature thing = Dog();
```

I know I can't instantiate interfaces and the like, but this is just a `Dog` being declared as a `Creature`.

I need some way of having one declaration work for all the children (i.e., being able to put `Dog()`, `Cat()`, or `Pig()` where `Dog()` is in the line above).

Can this be done in c++ or am I misusing inheritance and interfaces completely?

Answer (score 9):

Object types themselves are not polymorphic in C++. The line you've given declares a `Creature` object and then attempts to initialise it with a `Dog` object. If `Creature` weren't abstract, this would result in slicing - `thing` wouldn't be a `Dog` any more, it would just be a `Creature`. Since it is abstract, you simply can't have a `Creature` object anyway.

You need to use pointers or references for polymorphic behaviour. Consider for example:

```
Creature* thing = new Dog();
```

You can now dereference `thing` and use it as a `Creature`, even though it's dynamic type is `Dog`. However, using raw pointers like this is usually not recommended, as you have to manually ensure that the object is `delete`d at some point. The ownership can become confusing. Your best bet is to put it in a smart pointer, such as:

```
std::unique_ptr<Creature> thing(new Dog()); // or std::make_unique when we have it
```

Here, I've demonstrated `std::unique_ptr`, but the choice of smart pointer will depend on the ownership semantics for that object. A common alternative is `std::shared_ptr`.

To demonstrate polymorphism with references:

```
Dog dog;
Creature& thing = dog;
// Can now use dog as a Creature
```

Comment: Interesting! I'm curious about the bit with references you mentioned at the end. If `Creature` had a virtual method called `talk()` and `Dog` overrode it, would calling `thing`'s bark call `Creature`s or `Dog`s?

Comment: @CoreyMaddieBesmer It would call `Dog`'s, because, when called through  a pointer or reference, virtual member functions are looked up for the *dynamic* type of an object. The dynamic type of `thing` is `Dog`.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you have to realize the different between value and reference semantics, where-as in interpretet languages you tend to just deal with reference semantics (except for some odd cases with plain old data objects which have value semantics but besides the point).

In C++ all objects are values, e.g an object can never be `null`, this has the implication that declaration specifies the storage requirement.
Consider the following

```
struct creature {
};

struct dog : public creature {
    float cuteness;
};
```

The storage requirement for a dog is different than that of a creature, even if you allow the conversion this would result in slicing.
For example, will fido bark or be silent?
    #include

```
class creature {
public:
    virtual void speak() {
        std::cout << "..." << std::endl;
    }
};

class dog : public creature {
public:
    virtual void speak() {
        std::cout << "woof!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    creature fido;
    fido = dog();

    fido.speak();
    return 0;
}
```

However if you were to simply have a pointer or reference to the object it is a different matter.
By pointer.

```
creature* fido = new dog();
fido->speak();
delete fido;
```

By reference.

```
dog fido;
creature& c = fido;

c.speak();
```

Beyond the scope of this question, but optionally a smart pointer.

```
std::unique_ptr<creature> fido(new dog);
```